# Use of SSH in a linux shared hosting

Tags: linux, ssh, godaddy

what is the use of SSH in Linux Shared Deluxe Hosting in Godaddy.

Comment: Perhaps ask Godaddy support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It allows you to [ssh](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Secure_Shell) into your hosted server and make changes on the command line, instead of through a web interface like [cPanel](http://www.cpanel.net/).  Typically if you are on a windows machine you would use [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) to connect to the ssh server.  Then you can use regular linux command-line tools to edit files and such.

Comment: I am new to these things. can u say an example when i need to use ssh..